# VIM - How to select a substring

Tags: vim

I have the following line, that has no spaces -

> 123456789abcdefghij01234123456780900dfasdfsadfsadfsa

I want to select (highlight for yanking) 10 characters, starting at column 10.

I can navigate to column 10 by :10| but then how would I visually select ten characters starting under the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10|v9l
```

(without the colon) moves the cursor to column 10, enters visual mode and expands the selection 9 characters to the right, ready to yank.

Comment: Like everything in Vim: `:help l`.